# how to check if the first or the second element of a tuple matches a given value in python?

Tags: python, tuples

I want to find if the first element or the second element matches 3, if so
I want to append the tuple to mytuple_with_3.

```
mytuple=[(1,3),(4,9),(3,8)]
mytuple_with_3 = []

c = 0
for x in mytuple:
    if x[0][c] == 3 or x[c][1] == 3:
        mytuple_with_3.append(x)
    c += 1
```

result show show (1,3) and (3,8)

Comment: Some basic level of googling "list comprehension to filter tuple" should have found you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this list comprehension:

```
mytuple_with_3 = [i for i in mytuple if 3 in i]

>>> mytuple_with_3
[(1, 3), (3, 8)]
```

To limit it to only the first 2 elements, use:

```
mytuple_with_3 = [i for i in mytuple if 3 in i[:2]]
```